# Baudrate in a STM32L152 Discovery

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, baudrate

I have the following code:

```
#include "stm32l1xx.h" 
#include "..\Library_SDM.h" 
#include "..\Utiles_SDM.h"

int main(void){ 
unsigned char value = 'A'; 
Init_SDM(); 
Init_LCD();
// User button as Digital Input
GPIOA->MODER &= ~(1 << (0*2 +1)); 
GPIOA->MODER &= ~(1 << (0*2));
// No pull up-pull down (default)
GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~(11 << (0*2));
// Blue LED digital output  
GPIOB->MODER |= (0x01 << (2*6+1)); 
GPIOB->MODER &= ~(0x01 << (2*6));
// Blue LED as USART    
GPIOB->AFR[0] &= 0xF0FFFFFF; 
GPIOB->AFR[0] |= 0x07000000;
// USART configuration  
USART1->CR1 = 0x00000008;  // Oversampling by 16, 8-bit word, Parity control disabled, Transmission enabled
USART1->CR2 = 0x00000000;  // 1 stop bit
USART1->BRR = 0x00000D05;  // BRR= fck/(16*USARTDIV)=(32*10^6)/(9600)=0xD05
USART1->CR1 |= 0x01 << 13; // USART enable
LCD_Texto((unsigned char*)"PRESS"); 

while(1){
    if ((GPIOA->IDR&0x00000001)!=0) { 
        while ((GPIOA->IDR&0x00000001)!=0){ 
        wait(70000); 
    }

     while ((USART1->SR & 0x0080)== 0); // While with no body (to wait
                                        // for the transmission buffer to be ready)
        USART1->DR = value; 
        value++; 
        } 
    } //End of infinite while
}
```

When you press the button provided in the discovery board, the letter A is shown in the computer terminal (using Tera Term) and if pressed again is shown letter B and so on. The device is programmed using a 9600 bps configuration with a frecuency of 32MHz.

If I change the `BRR` value to be `8AE` instead of `D05` the communication will be 14400 bps which is what I want, but the program does not work as expected (the program has to do exactly what it is said above but instead of having a rate of 9600 bps, at 14400 bps ). I don't know why it does not work at 14400 bps since I guess it is just how fast the information travels, or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: *"the program does not work as expected"* How does it work then? Please describe the "unexpected" behaviour. And please indent your code properly, otherwise it's quite hard to see how all those `while` loops are related.

Comment: And you could perhaps use symbolic constants defined in CMSIS (like `USART_CR1_TE`) instead of numerc ones.

Comment: Get out a scope or logic analyzer and see what it *does* send.  Also show the version that doesn't alongside the one that does.